# Check if a matrix has support

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, decision-problems

From [Sinkhorn & Knopp](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102992505) (1967):

> If $\mathbf{A}$ is an $N \times N$ matrix and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1, \dots, N\}$, then the sequence of elements $a_{1, \sigma(1)}, \dots, a_{N, \sigma(N)}$ is called the **diagonal** of $\mathbf{A}$, corresponding to $\sigma$.

In order to guarantee the convergence of Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm for square matrix balancing, we require that a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ **has support**, that is, it must contain at least one diagonal with only positive elements.

As an example:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & 3 \\
   0 & 5 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

This matrix has support because the entries $1$, $3$, $5$ reside in a diagonal.

Is there an easy way to check if a matrix has support?

Comment: It's not particularly efficient, but every invertible matrix has support. So, row-reduction (or any test for invertibility) gives a sufficient condition for $A$ having support

Comment: Is it also a necessary condition?

Comment: No, it is not${}$